# Probability mean is less than 5 given that poisson distribution states it is 6

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to find the probability that mean is less than 5 given that poisson distribution states it is 6
ie find p(x<5|x~po(6))

Here is the actual question:
Two grocers agree that the daily demand for a particular item has Poisson distribution. However, grocer A
claims that the mean demand is 3 items per day, while grocer B claims that the mean demand is 6 items per
day. They agree to resolve the disagreement by observing the demand on one particular day: B agrees to
accept A’s claim if the observed demand is 4 or less, and A agrees to accept B’s claim if the observed demand
is 5 or more.
(a) Calculate the probability that A’s claim is accepted when, in fact, B’s claim is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant finding the probability of a Poisson rv with mean 6 taking value less than 5. That is the same as the probability of a Poisson rv taking values less or equal to 4 since Poisson is a discrete prob. distribution. Also, since Poisson variate can only take non-negative discrete values, the required probability will be the sum of the probabilities of a Poisson variate taking values 0,1,2,3,4 and you can calculate individual probabilities from the Poisson pmf. You can pick it from here.